# Creating function in R

Tags: r

I just started learning to write functions in R. As a start, I am trying to replicate the summary function as below. But not able to return expected result

```
summary_function <- function(df = as.data.frame(x)){
  result <- summary(x)
  return(as.table(result))
}

> summary_function(df = iris)  ## below is the output I am getting
  Length Class  Mode   
a   4    -none- numeric
b  10    -none- numeric
c  20    -none- numeric
d 100    -none- numeric
```

Expected output is actual summary of iris. Is there a way to achieve this?

I also tried with below function so that the output should return first 10 rows of the dataset. But the output is not returning as expected

```
first_ten_rows <- function(df = x){
  result <- head(x, n = 10)
  return(result)
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing `function(df = x)` ? Just keep it as `function(x)`

Answer (score 2):

the "as.table()" in your attempt was coercing the summary object into a less legible format

```
summary_function <- function(df = as.data.frame(x)){
  result <- summary(df)
  return(result)
}
```

---

R typically returns the last calculated line too, so if you want to shorten it:

```
summary_function <- function(df = as.data.frame(x)){
    summary(df)
}
```

would get you the same result.

---

If you would like to read more about "summary" objects, running

```
?summary
```

will open more documentation in the help panel in RStudio

---

In your second question, there is an "x" out of place in "head()" which should be "df"

```
first_ten_rows <- function(df = x){
  result <- head(df, n = 10)
  return(result)
}
```